# Is it possible to get the calculated frame given an array of constraints?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to animate a view from a thumbnail to a fullscreen view when touched. When the view is in thumbnail mode it is a subview of the UITableView.tableFooterView. When I animate to fullscreen I move the view to the controller's root view before updating the constraints. I do this because the tableview clips the subviews.

This is working perfectly, but when I try to do the reverse animation it's not so easy. I have to first move the thumbnail view back into a subview of the UITableView.tableFooterView before I can update the constraints. I then undo the constraints (basically set them to what there where originally). This works but the animation does not look right because as soon as the view is moved back into UITableView.tableFooterView it's clipped again by the UITableView and the animation is partially hidden behind all the tableview adornments!

My idea is to get the calculated frame for the constraints and perform old fashioned frame animation and then install the constraints after.

**Is there a known way to ask the layout system given an array of constraints what will the frame be without actually installing those constraints?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a way.

Note that the constraints you define (`NSLayoutConstraint`) are not the only constraints. Other constraints are defined by the properties of your views (e.g. intrinsic content size, hugging priorities etc.).

I guess this is something that would work better with autoresizing instead of autolayout.

Another solution would be to use a hidden placeholder view in the table footer. When you are returning the view back into the footer, you can just ask for the frame of the placeholder.

Comment: Great idea about the placeholder view! Will give that a go. Animation seems a lot harder now with AutoLayout. :-(